# Calling Method on Object

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project that involves making a email class. I have a Java background, and cannot seem to figure out the syntax for calling methods on objects.

I'll abbreviate the code:

FILE 1:

```
class Emails {

protected $to;

public function Emails ($_to) {
 //constructor function. 
  $to = $_to;
}

public function getTo () {
  return $to;
}
```

FILE 2:

```
require("../phpFunctions/EmailClass.php");//include the class file
$email = new Emails("<email here>");
echo $email->getTo();//get email and return it
```

However, getTo() keeps returning either nothing, or, if I change the return to $this->$to, I receive an "empty field" error.

Please help me understand how methods work in this instance (and forgive the pun...). In Java, you would just call email.getTo()...

Comment: Just a tip: Function constructs are very php 4, you might wanna try using `__construct`

Comment: $this->to at place of $this->$to

Comment: Worth reading: [PHP classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: I don't know about java, but in general the php manual is great and comes up first in almost any Google search.

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks for the tip. That's how I'm used to doing constructors in Java :) But I've now updated my PHP code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function __construct ($_to) {
  $this->to = $_to;
}    
public function getTo () {
  return $this->to;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! You don't know how long I've been banging my head at this simple problem...

Answer (score 0):

For copy and paste sake:

```
class Emails {

protected $to;

public function __construct($_to) {
 //constructor function. 
  $this->to = $_to;
}

public function getTo () {
  return $this->to;
}

}
```

Using `$this` scope will get the variable defined within the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP variables are not instance scoped unless prefixed with `$this`

```
public function getTo () {
  // $to is scoped to the current function
  return $to;
}

public function getTo () {
  // Get $to scoped to the current instance.
  return $this->to;
}
```